# In making CSS for printing a web page, how many pixels wide is 8 inches?

Tags: css, pdf, media-queries, jspdf

I'm making my web page into a pdf via jsPDF and it only allows sizing in points, millimeters and centimeters. I know the pixel to point conversion is 1 pixel to 0.75 points, but how do I convert when I don't know the DPI and every conversion tool changes the values based on that?

My CSS would always be:

```
.something { width: 64em; } /* (1024 pixels on normal display) */
```

But, when that's converted to a printed page, what would it be? How do I ensure I'm making it the right width for the printed page?

Comment: for printing i guess you use a value that fits with the size of your paper inches or centimeters not em :)

Comment: Why not use `in` ? lol `.something { width: 8in; }`

Comment: Your `em` is as unreliable as `px`. It is based on the *current font size*, and you may or may not know how large your font is. (If you do and it is stated in pts, then you might have a handle. However, if the font size also is stated in pixels, then you only moved the problem one layer up.) Use Real World measurements instead.